# Подскажите примеры создания библиотек на С/С++, подключаемых к php

Tags: c, php, c++

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, примеры создания библиотек на С/С++/С#, подключаемых к php.
Хотя бы самое примитивное, типа библиотека имеет функцию SayHello(NAME) и выводит привет+имя. И её подключение в php.

А вообще хочется реализовать объекты, например, люди, где вначале их создадим и считаем из базы, а потом будем ссылаться на библиотеку, а она будет производить поиск, удаление, и т.д.

Подобного ещё не делал. Интересен прирост производительности с большими данными, и как вообще это работает.

Answer (score 4):

[Вот интересная штука.](http://www.php-cpp.com/)

Answer (score 2):

[[@mks](/users/5886/mks)](/users/5886/mks),
Скорее, псевдо-язык [Zephir](http://habrahabr.ru/post/194838/), на котором phalcon написан.

Answer (score 2):

Несколько лет назад, когда было побольше свободного времени, писал посты о создании расширений для php на сях, возможно это то, что вы ищите http://adobkin.com/php-extensions/

Answer (score 1):

php-pecl - предоставит огромное количество примеров с иходниками. Там же можно разжиться [информацией](http://pecl.php.net/support.php)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [phalcon](http://www.phalconphp.com/ru/), как утверждает оф. сайт полностью написан на С.